# Getting information of Button on click

Tags: android

I have a `Map<String, String>` where it stores `ID` and `Name`.     I am creating buttons from this map, where the button text is set to Name. *How can I get information of Button on `click` event?* Say, I want to get ID when a button is clicked.

Please note that the ID is unique, but Name can be duplicated.

I have tried setting `setHint(ID)` to button while creation. But, I don't find any `getHint()` method on `View` under onClick().

Comment: Button is a View and View has setId() and getId().  Can't you just use those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the ID in the Tag property of the button and retrieve it with `getTag()`

e.g.

```
Button b=new Button();
b.setTag(YourID);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("TAG", "My Tag is " + v.getTag());
    }
});
```